# Fetch all lines starting with hash tags using php

Tags: php, regex

i want to fetch all lines starting with hash tag from several lines of code for ex:

```
#title : Test Ticket 
Hotel : Test Hotel
#Category : Ticket Test
Note : This is just test note
#Start Date : 11/19/2015
#End Date : 11/20/2015
#Emails : demos@gmail.com,test@gmail.com
#Flag : Call
priority : High
```

So i am trying to do by following line of code

```
preg_match_all("/^#(.*)$/m",$output,$m);
```

but its not working please suggest me some other idea.

Thanks

Comment: i have already tried that but its not working so i am asking same thing

Comment: @bobblebubble That's exactly the same OP wrote in his question..

Comment: @Naruto I thought he just messed the variables, [because it works](https://eval.in/471846).

Comment: What's the output you are getting in `$m`?

Comment: @SanjayRathod: Check this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iB8wD5/1) and [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/CyyQHr). Do you find your mistake? I guess you do.

Comment: @stribizhev Why do you think the use of a capture group is the "mistake" ? Of course there are other more elegant ways to omit `#` from matches if wanted.

Comment: @bobblebubble: I do not understand you. Where did I say there is a mistake in the use of a capturing group? I am just sure OP does not know how to use the preg_replace results. I am rather confident because the regex is quite correct. No one mentioned that `#` should be omitted.

Comment: @stribizhev Oh, then I misunderstood you because I already mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all("/^\#(.*)$/m",$output,$m);
```

- `^` assert position at start of a line
- `\#` matches the character # literally
- `.*` matches any character (except newline)
- `$` assert position at end of a line
- `m` modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

Comment: @bobblebubble.Thanks, Edited.

Comment: So now whats the difference between your answer and OPs answer only escaping `#` over here which is not needed over here

Comment: The difference is escaping the `#` character

Comment: `$m = "#title : Test Ticket 
Hotel : Test Hotel
#Category : Ticket Test
Note : This is just test note
#Start Date : 11/19/2015
#End Date : 11/20/2015
#Emails : demos@gmail.com,test@gmail.com
#Flag : Call
priority : High";

$x = preg_match_all("/^\#(.*)$/m",$m,$output);`

Comment: That won't make any difference OP's regex is working perfectly check [**this**](https://eval.in/471858) and I think I've already said that you have escaped `#` nothing else and that won't make any difference over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804475/fetch-all-lines-starting-with-hash-tags-using-php#comment55374849_33804519)

Answer (score 0):

# is a delimeter in regular expression. so escape the character from the expression:

```
preg_match_all("/^\#(.*)$/m",$string,$m);
```